# Overwrite range in Excel Worksheet with values from array

Tags: excel, vba

Can I overwrite a range in Excel with values from an array?

I have tried something like this:

```
rng = "A1:B10"

WB.Worksheets("Sheet_1").Range(rng) = arr
```

Where arr was originally from the same worksheet with the same range, just with some more adjustments.

Thank you

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: I usually go with `Range.Resize` to fit it with the array, always works like a charm.

Comment: What kind of array is `arr`? Maybe you should transpose it. How did you build this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eg:

```
Dim rng As String, arr

rng = "A1:B10"

arr = WB.Worksheets("Sheet_1").Range(rng).Value  '<< read to array

arr(1, 1) = "Hello"   'modify array data

WB.Worksheets("Sheet_1").Range(rng).Value = arr  '<< write array back to sheet

'or

WB.Worksheets("Sheet_1").Range("A1").Resize(ubound(arr,1), ubound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
```